# Make border of input field not-clickable

Tags: html, css

Whenever I select the border of an input box

```
<input type='text'>
```

in Firefox 44.0.2, the cursor is misplaced and I can't type anything. This does not happen in Chrome. Here is an example

[image]

and a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ymne5j72/).

How can I prevent that the border of my input field is selectable in Firefox?

Edit: I am using a PC, Win 7 Professional, 64 Bit

Comment: It doesnt happens on my firefox 44;

Comment: This might be jsfiddle causing this.  Try this one: http://output.jsbin.com/dasuyohone.  One of the things to like jsbin over jsfiddle is that it doesn't place so much in frames.

Comment: @JosephMarikle it happens also there. I have the issue on youtube, google everywhere. I am using Windows 7

Comment: I think your computer has issues, dude.  I ran it through browser stack with Win 7 and FF 34: http://i.imgur.com/3t6L2Yd.png.  Cursor works as expected and browser stack uses physical machines, not emulators.

Comment: Have you tried different browsers?  Maybe you just need to reinstall FF.

Comment: @JosephMarikle yes I have tried Chrome, there it works. I just reinstalled Firefox, but the issue remains :/.

Comment: @Adam PC or Mac? My money is Mac, am I right?

Comment: @zer00ne I am using a PC, Win 7 Professional, 64 Bit

Comment: Mac, Firefox 44.0.2, it doesnt happen. Linux, Firefox 44, it doesn't happen. Windows 7 Firefox 44 it doesn't happen. It's your machine. Maybe the addons you've installed.

Comment: Are you using plugins with Firefox? Try disabling/enabling all of them. Some plugins tend to mess up the behavior of the browser.. BTW I'm using win8 64bit 44.0.2, everything works fine ;)

Comment: I disabled all my Plugins ( I only use adblocker and proxtube). Still doesnt work. I am currently reinstalling win 7 and try to see if it fixes the error.